# aws ebs csi driver unable to create the persistent volume with IAM role attached to ec2-instance

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am trying to create the dynamic PV with aws ebs-csi driver, but it giving me error and this is start happening after moving from 0.8.1 to v0.10.1 version. Also attached the IAM role to my ec2-instance but still giving me 'EmptyEC2RoleList: empty EC2 Role list' not sure what else need to be updated.

Getting following error:

```
k describe pvc claim1
Name:          claim1
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  gp3
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age                   From                                                                                      Message
  ----     ------                ----                  ----                                                                                      -------
  Normal   ExternalProvisioning  3m19s (x63 over 18m)  persistentvolume-controller                                                               waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "ebs.csi.aws.com" or manually created by system administrator
  Normal   Provisioning          1s (x12 over 18m)     ebs.csi.aws.com_ebs-csi-controller-67cb5bb848-4t4h9_9db1a096-d0d7-43de-9801-456c9614ceb9  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/claim1"
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed    1s (x12 over 18m)     ebs.csi.aws.com_ebs-csi-controller-67cb5bb848-4t4h9_9db1a096-d0d7-43de-9801-456c9614ceb9  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "gp3": rpc error: code = Internal desc = NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain
caused by: EnvAccessKeyNotFound: failed to find credentials in the environment.
SharedCredsLoad: failed to load profile, .
EmptyEC2RoleList: empty EC2 Role list
```