# AWS IAM Role for Service Account with EBS CSI driver: could not create volume in EC2: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks

I have successfully installed the AWS EBS CSI driver to my EKS cluster.

This is meant to be using the ["IAM Role for Service Account"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html) technique.

I am trying to utilise the checkout example app that AWS have [given here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-sample-app.html)
The pod will not come up (pending) and the PVC is showing this:

```
Name:          ebs-claim
Namespace:     test
StorageClass:  ebs-sc
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        app=ebs-claim
               com.mylabel.contact=dl-myteam.dlonp1
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
               volume.kubernetes.io/selected-node: ip-10-232-100-115.ec2.internal
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       meme-ebs
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age               From                                                                                      Message
  ----     ------              ----              ----                                                                                      -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  27s               persistentvolume-controller                                                               storageclass.storage.k8s.io "ebs-sc" not found
  Normal   Provisioning        8s (x4 over 25s)  ebs.csi.aws.com_ebs-csi-controller-6dfdb77cdf-fbsbz_1760973c-09bb-43ab-b005-ffcd818447fc  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "test/ebs-claim"
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  5s (x4 over 22s)  ebs.csi.aws.com_ebs-csi-controller-6dfdb77cdf-fbsbz_1760973c-09bb-43ab-b005-ffcd818447fc  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "ebs-sc": rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not create volume "pvc-05efbff8-9506-4003-9bab-e1ce4719bc1c": could not create volume in EC2: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain
caused by: EnvAccessKeyNotFound: failed to find credentials in the environment.
SharedCredsLoad: failed to load profile, .
EC2RoleRequestError: no EC2 instance role found
caused by: EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request
```

Similar to an issue I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68466193/aws-ebs-csi-driver-unable-to-create-the-persistent-volume-with-iam-role-attached), but had no answers.

Can anyone suggest things to try?  Seems like the IAM role is not wired thru to the API that mounts the volume on EC2?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and fixed it by updating the Amazon EBS CSI driver IAM role as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/csi-iam-role.html)

### Set up driver permissions

1. Create a new IAM role for granting the `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity` action

1a. Copy the following contents to a file that's named `aws-ebs-csi-driver-trust-policy.json`

```yaml
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.region-code.amazonaws.com/id/EXAMPLED539D4633E53DE1B71EXAMPLE"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "oidc.eks.region-code.amazonaws.com/id/EXAMPLED539D4633E53DE1B71EXAMPLE:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com",
          "oidc.eks.region-code.amazonaws.com/id/EXAMPLED539D4633E53DE1B71EXAMPLE:sub": "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ebs-csi-controller-sa"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

❕Note: Remember to add the audience `sts.amazonaws.com` for `aud: sts.amazonaws.com` and also to add both for `aud` and `sub` parameters in Condition section as mentioned above ↑↑

1b. Create a new IAM role `amazoneks_ebs_csi_driver_role` using above `aws-ebs-csi-driver-trust-policy.json`

```bash
aws iam create-role \
  --role-name amazoneks_ebs_csi_driver_role \
  --assume-role-policy-document file://"aws-ebs-csi-driver-trust-policy.json"
```

1c. Attach the `AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy` AWS managed policy to IAM role `amazoneks_ebs_csi_driver_role` with the following command

```bash
aws iam attach-role-policy \
  --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy \
  --role-name amazoneks_ebs_csi_driver_role
```

2. [Optional] If you are using custom [KMS key](http://aws.amazon.com/kms/) for encryption on your Amazon EBS volumes, customise the IAM role as needed. Read Step.4 [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/csi-iam-role.html)

❕Note: Make sure to update the commands and policies to a different name.

---

### Set up EKS IAM roles for service accounts (IRSA)

Create the [service account](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/38b60ac2b52c0b0c9e55f6a962c98699367b30d4/deploy/kubernetes/base/serviceaccount-csi-controller.yaml) with the same name used in OIDC auth sub i.e. `ebs-csi-controller-sa` for above created IAM role `amazoneks_ebs_csi_driver_role` in your EKS cluster and make sure you add below annotation to service account:

```yaml
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/amazoneks_ebs_csi_driver_role
```

```yaml
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: ebs-csi-controller-sa
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: aws-ebs-csi-driver
  #Enable if EKS IAM roles for service accounts (IRSA) is used. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html for details.
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/amazoneks_ebs_csi_driver_role
EOF
```

❕Note: Make sure that there is NO typos in IAM role arn for annotation. `ebs-csi-controller-sa` SA is added to `controller` deployment

---

### Finally restart the Amazon EBS CSI driver controller

```bash
kubectl -n kube-system rollout restart deployment/ebs-csi-controller
```

---

### Verify that the Amazon EBS CSI driver is working

You can test the CSI driver functionality by deploying a sample application.

Read [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-sample-app.html)

---

❕Note: You can also read this [troubleshoot issues with my EBS volume mounts in Amazon EKS guide](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-troubleshoot-ebs-volume-mounts)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with the service account that your efs csi driver is using. For example, make sure it's using the right role with the right trust policy for your EKS cluster. For example check the right annotation below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: aws-efs-csi-driver
  name: efs-csi-controller-sa
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/AmazonEKS_EFS_CSI_DriverRole
```

And the role that you are using has the right trust policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.region-code.amazonaws.com/id/EXAMPLED539D4633E53DE1B71EXAMPLE"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "oidc.eks.region-code.amazonaws.com/id/EXAMPLED539D4633E53DE1B71EXAMPLE:sub": "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:efs-csi-controller-sa"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html) are pretty clear. (It worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the created ServiceAccounts have the correct IRSA annotations.

If you are using the helm chart, and doing an upgrade from an older version, double check the location of the IRSA ServiceAccount annotation (they may have changed, had me stumped for a bit as to why things didn't work).